# Как подключить .emacs, после установке через brew?

Tags: emacs

Установил так:
1) curl -fsSL https://rawgit.com/kube/42homebrew/master/install.sh | zsh 
2) brew install emacs
После этого файл .emacs из директории пользователя не подключается к Emacs. Из-за этого пропала подсветка синтаксиса (раньше она сама включалась, теперь ее вручную приходится включать).
Я понимаю ,что нужно куда-то в папке .brew закинуть, но куда именно?

Comment: Почитайте [The Emacs Initialization File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) и [How Emacs Finds Your Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init). Проверьте значение HOME. А еще распишите подробнее, как вы emacs запускаете, где он в системе установлен, да и что за ОС у вас (судя по brew какой-то Мак?)

Comment: Честно говоря у меня emacs всегда нормально собирался/устанавливался и запускался (года так с 87-го) на всех системах

Comment: Еще. Посмотрите буфер `*Messages*` (или что-то в этом роде) сразу после старта